# Is Barbie (2023 film) on-topic? If so, how should we tag questions about it?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

I am wondering if the 2023 film *[Barbie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1517268/reference/)* is considered on-topic. The film depicts a fantasy world called Barbie Land, where various Barbies, Kens, and other characters such as Allan live. A significant portion of the film takes place in this world, while the rest follows Barbie and Ken as they visit the “Real World”. Is this film on-topic for this site? If so, how should we tag questions about it? The question I have in mind is about the meaning or humor behind a line said by one of the Barbies in the film.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes the *Barbie* film should be considered on topic. I'm unsure why it wouldn't be as the whole premise is literally that toys are alive living in a different world but also existing as toys in the human world. On top of that the toys and humans can travel between the two worlds. The ending is also probably even more fantastical.

If we need more evidence though note that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbie_(film)) describes the film as *"a 2023 American fantasy comedy film"* and on [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1517268/) it is tagged as Fantasy in the genres.

About tagging the film I would suggest going with [barbie-2023](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/barbie-2023) so we don't confuse anyone thinking all of Barbie would be on topic here which I don't think it is.

Comment: Agreed. There's lots of fantastical stuff happening in this film including the ghost of the creator of Barbie being a character.

Comment: Sweet, I'll start. Question 1: **How does one become Kenough?**

Comment: @Möoz, I haven't watched the movie, but I'm going to say that everyone can be [Kenough](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kenough), but only a few select can be Kenobi. ;-)